# How to change the size and style of the text in the title on the main page of the application?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have an application and I need to change the style and size of the text on the main page, only where and how I can not even imagine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters I would suggest you start using the [AppCompat libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/toolbar-compatibility).

The AppCompat library is basically used for backward compatibility for Android features and hence is a must-have for every Android app. More information in the link abov2

Once you are done with this you might wanna take a look at the [Support Library Toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/toolbar-compatibility)

Basically you will have to use the below toolbar:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Once you do that you can get the toolbar instance in your MainActivty and start making the required change.

Good luck, feel free to get back in case queries.